# Masterpage in php

Tags: php, master-pages

I'm trying to incorporate something like Masterpages into a website, and have been wondering about something.

Should you have one template site where you require the header, footer and content(by passing a variable which points to a content file).

example of template.php:

```
require(header.php);
require($content.php);
require(footer.php);
```

or should you just require the header and footer template in every site.

example of sonething_site.php:

```
require(header.php);
//content here
require(footer.php);
```

Thanks

Comment: So many questions: What type of site? How diverse is the content? Have you looked at how wordpress does it(great php coding)?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Answer (score 9):

Simple Solution would be to have a file for master page and then calling it from your other pages, if you do not want to use any third-party template engine.

Example: **master.php**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Title at Masterpage</title>
   </head>

   <body>

      <div id="menu">
         <a href="index.php">Home</a>
         <a href="about.php">About Us</a>
         <a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
      </div>

      <div><?php echo $content; ?></div>

      <div id="footer">Footer to be repeated at all pages</div>

   </body>
</html>
```

In your page for example **about.php**

```
<?php
   $content = 'This is about us page content';
   include('master.php');
?>
```

**NOTE:** If you want to have page contents in a separate file rather than setting $content variable, you can include the file in your page and assign it to $content. Then in *master.php* use `include($content)` instead of `echo $content`

Answer (score 3):

your first approach `$content.php` doesnt seem very secure, i can insert my remote page there.

So your second approach is better, take a look at smarty. it s a great template engine.

and be careful!!

Comment: How could you insert your remote web page there ?

Comment: @Nacereddine: [Register globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php), possibly.

Comment: ever heard of MVC? you dont insert a page, to a template. look at zend framework controller and use of smarty as well. if you are not carefull, anyone can insert a page to your site.

Answer (score 2):

```
First: Create a template page, I called mine master.php.

<body>
<div><?php include('menu.php');?></div>
<div><?php include($page_content);?></div>
<div><?php include('footer.php');?></div>
</body>

Second: Create a content piece, for example about_text.php.
<p>This is information about me.</p>

Third: Create the page with the actual name you want to use:
<?php
$page_content = 'about_text.php';
include('master.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is better to go with option A. There is one template file and all of the pages only have content. The reason for this is that if you need to change the architecture of your site or the way that your template page behaves, you aren't screwed because you have to edit 1000 pages.

Unless you have a reason to do otherwise it is also not a bad idea to use a CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a PHP template engine like [Dwoo](http://dwoo.org/) or [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) .

The feature you may like 
[Template Inheritance](http://wiki.dwoo.org/index.php/TemplateInheritance)